# How to make new variable that takes 1 if the string in another column contains a word with varying punctuation and font size?

Tags: r, string, multiple-columns, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a column that looks something like this

```
col1 
"business"
"BusinesS"
"education"
"some BUSINESS ."
"business of someone, that is cool"
" not the b word"
"busi ness"
"busines." 
"businesses"
"something else"
```

And I need an efficient way of getting all this string data into a new value

```
col1                col2
NA                  1
NA                  1
"education"         NA
NA                  1
NA                  1
" not the b word"   NA
NA                  1
NA                  1
NA                  1
"something else"    NA
```

So the common denominator is "busines", but I don't know how to efficiently make it sort out all the spaces, punctuation, lower/uppercases, other words etc. in one mutate that creates a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) 
df %>%
  mutate(col2 = ifelse(str_detect(col1, "(?i)busi\\s?ness?"),
                       1,
                       NA)
```

We can use `ifelse` to set `1` if `str_detect` detects any form of `business`, and `NA` if it doesn't. Note that `(?i)` makes the match case-insensitive and `?` in `\\s?` and `s?` makes the preceding item optional; so `\\s?` matches an optional space and `s?` matches an optional literal `s`

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask what does the ?i and the \\s? and do specifically?

Comment: Perfect! I think you are missing a ) in the end, but it works.

Comment: No I don't think there's a `)` missing

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all non word characters using `gsub` and than use `grepl` to detect `busines`:

```
+grepl("busines", gsub("\\W+", "", s), ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Another way would be to use `agrepl` for *Approximate String Matching*, where here `1L` gives the maximum distance to the given pattern.

```
+agrepl("busines", s, 1L, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

`agrep` can also be a solution in case you are looking for `business` instead of `busines`:

```
+agrepl("business", gsub("\\W+", "", s), 1L, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Data:

```
s <- c("business","BusinesS","education","some BUSINESS .",
       "business of someone, that is cool"," not the b word",
       "busi ness","busines." ,"businesses","something else")
```